# Android Search Dialog modification?

Tags: android, search-dialog

I've got a functioning Search Dialog in my app. My question is: Can the search dialog be modified so that the input text field and search button (that are present at the top of the screen) don't disappear when the ListView populates? So I'd like the input interface to always be present until I move away from the Search Activity by clicking on a list item. And even better, can the software keyboard only appear when the input interface is acted upon? Are these tweaks to the Android Search Dialog possible in 2.2, which I'm authoring to?

[image: I would like this searchbar NOT disappear when the ListView populates]

I'd like this search bar from the Search Dialog to remain when the ListView populates.

Answer (score 0):

yes try using a linear layout as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

--------your search bar layout

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
```

If you need it as a alert dialog simply apply theme attribute as dialog  to the activity which has this layout

Comment: `Search Dialog` is not "search bar".

Comment: yes search dialog is not search bar. I just used it because he is interested in spelling it a search dialog

Answer (score 0):

According to [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) document:

> An activity can frequently transition in and out of the foreground—for
>   example, `onPause()` is called when the device goes to sleep or when a
>   dialog appears.

I guess that means that you cannot change the state of ListView until the Dialog is displayed.